# Как выбрать class/id с помощью JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Я начал переучиваться с `jQuery` на `JS` и это труднее, чем казалось.
Вот мой стандартный код на `jQuery`:

```
function planeChoose() {
  $('.primary_search .dollar').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var tarGet = $('.primary_search .flight_type');
    if (!tarGet.hasClass('pop_up_flight')) {
      tarGet.addClass('pop_up_flight');
    } else {
      tarGet.removeClass('pop_up_flight');
    }
  });
  $('.hotel .dollar').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var tarGet = $('.hotel .flight_type_hotel');
    if (!tarGet.hasClass('pop_up_flight_hotel')) {
      tarGet.addClass('pop_up_flight_hotel');
    } else {
      tarGet.removeClass('pop_up_flight_hotel');
    }
  })
}
```

Можете его переписать на `JS`, пожалуйста?
Что бы я мог брать его за ориентир.

Comment: Что вы уже пробовали сделать? Что **конкретно** не получается?

Comment: Думать не получилось(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="primary_search">
    <div class="flight_type"></div>
    <a class="dollar" href="#">$</a>
</div>

<div class="hotel">
    <div class="flight_type_hotel"></div>
    <a class="dollar" href="#">$</a>
</div>

<script>
    document.querySelector('.primary_search .dollar').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var tarGet = document.querySelector('.primary_search .flight_type');
        tarGet.classList.toggle('pop_up_flight');
    });

    document.querySelector('.hotel .dollar').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var tarGet = document.querySelector('.hotel .flight_type_hotel');
        tarGet.classList.toggle('pop_up_flight_hotel');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, второй раз уже помогаешь)

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста :)

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы получить элемент с помощью id используте`getElementById` на объекте `document`.

`document.getElementById('emenent_id')`.

Чтобы получить элемент с помощью class используте`getElementsByClassName` на объекте `document`.

`document.getElementsByClassName('emenent_class-name')`.

https://learn.javascript.ru/searching-elements-dom

Answer (score 1):

Возьми за ориентир хороший учебник по JS - это куда лучше будет.

```js
function planeChoose(){
  // document.querySelectorAll - ищет все элементы по селектору, правда в jQuery есть уникальные селекторs, типа :contains
  // Array.from - найденные элементы возвращаются как объект NodeList, для удобства превращаем их в массив
  // Array.forEach - перебирает массив
  // Element.addEventListener - вешает обработчик на событие
  
  Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.primary_search .dollar')).forEach(e => e.addEventListener('click', tmp1));
  
  function tmp1(e) {
    let tmp = null;
    e.preventDefault();
    
    // document.querySelector - возвращает только один элемент по селектору, судя по коду именно один и должен находится
    // classList.toggle - переключает класс: если он есть, то убирает, отсутствует - назначает
    ((tmp = document.querySelector('.primary_search .flight_type')) !== null && tmp.classList.toggle('pop_up_flight'));
  };
  
  Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.hotel .dollar')).forEach(e => e.addEventListener('click', tmp2));
  
  function tmp2(e){
    let tmp = null;
    e.preventDefault();
    
    ((tmp = document.querySelector('.hotel .flight_type_hotel')) !== null && tmp.classList.toggle('pop_up_flight_hotel'));
  }
}
```

P. S. Пока строчил, уже ответ написали и приняли :)

Comment: спасибо за труд)

Comment: @НикитаЩипилов, пожалуйста.